# How to make the length of a nested list equal to the value of a number in a list, using list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, nested, list-comprehension

I'm really new to Python, so forgive me if this is a ridiculously simple question.
I have a given list

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Now I want to make a list e, using list comprehension, that contains a list for each odd element of list x. All inner elements of this list should be true and the number of list elements is given by the current number of x. So it should look like this:

```
[[], [True, True], [True, True, True, True], ...]
```

The code I have so far is:

```
e = [[True for z in x] for z in x if z % 2 != 0]
```

When printed I get a list, where the amount of nested lists is equal to the amount of odd numbers in list x, but all of them contain True ten times. What do I have to do to make the lengths of the inner lists equal to the values of the odd numbers?

Comment: By "odd element of the list" you seem to mean "elements at even index". If so, that is a somewhat confusing way to refer to them. Perhaps you could clarify.

Comment: You say you want it for odd elements, but you make `list`s of even length...

Comment: If you do mean elements at even index, the answers could all simplify quite a bit, by removing the remainder tests (which are inaccurate if the goal is to test the index, not the value) in favor of just looping over `x[::2]`.

Comment: One of the ways that your example is confusing is that you picked a list where every element of the list is equal to its index. It would be much more enlightening if you had picked an example like `[0,4,3,5,6,7,6,8,9]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should do what you want:

```
[[True for _ in range(z)] for z in x if z % 2 != 0]
```

The difference is in the inner comprehension, `[True for _ in range(z)]`.

Previously, you were iterating over each `z` in `x` - so, for each iteration, `z` is an integer out of `x`. Then, for each unique `z`, you were iterating over *the entire `x`* again. Since `x` has 10 elements, that gives you 10 iterations.

Instead, what you want to do is produce an array of `[True]` with length `z`. `range(z)` gives you a guaranteed iterable of length `z` for which you can generate as many `True`s as you need.

The innermost variable name, I replaced with a `_`, because it isn't used.

Comment: I even tried range(z) but it didn't work because I wrote `True for z in range(z)`. Didn't know I could use `_`. Thank you so much!

Comment: This is a good answer -- but differs from what OP claims is the desired output.

Comment: @laryberry `_` is the standard 'placeholder, this isn't used for anything' variable name, but it would work equally well with any variable name that you haven't used elsewhere in the expression (e.g. `a`, in this case)

Answer (score 1):

First, the if-condition should be `z % 2 == 0`, then to create a list of `True` values you can use `[True] * z`:

```py
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

e = [[True] * z for z in x if z % 2 == 0]
print(e)
```

Prints:

```
[[], [True, True], [True, True, True, True], [True, True, True, True, True, True], [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]]
```

---

If you don't want to use `[True] * z` you can do:

```py
e = [[True for _ in range(z)] for z in x if z % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the reason *not* to use `[True] * z` would be if `True` is replaced with some other mutable type. For `bool`, sequence multiplication is perfectly safe and much faster, but if you were making inner `list`s of `list`s, the nested comprehension syntax is the only safe form.

Comment: Thank you so much for these two options!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `range` with `step==2`.

```
res = [[True]*e for e in range(0,9,2)]
# Or
res = [[True for _ in range(e)] for e in range(0,9,2)]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[[], [True, True], [True, True, True, True], [True, True, True, True, True, True], [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]]
```

Explanation:

```
>>> list(range(0,9,2))
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching for odd numbers could be done like this:

```
def generate_number_list(quantity: int):
    """
    This creates a list of numbers
    """
    number_list = []
    for number in range(quantity):
        number_list.append(number) 
        
    return number_list


def main():
    number_list = generate_number_list(10)
    odd_number_sub_lists = []
    
    # Be careful with list comprehensions. Storing them
    # could cause unexpected behaviour
    [
        odd_number_sub_lists.append(
            
            # Nested list comprehension that uses the current_number
            # as a range, only when its an odd number.
            [True for count in range(current_number)]
        )
        for current_number in number_list
        
        # As you typed odd Numbers. All of the previous
        # statements only work if the current_number
        # divided by two gives a residue greater than 0
        if (current_number % 2 > 0)  
    ]
    return odd_number_sub_lists
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = main()
    print(result)
```

Result:

```
[[True], [True, True, True], [True, True, True, True, True], [True, True, True, True, True, True, True], [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]]
```

Now, for the output you wanted, it would be for **even** numbers. The only thing you would need to change is this statement:

```
if (current_number % 2 > 0)
```

For this:

```
if (current_number % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: Seems overly complicated for a problem that can be solved in one line of code.

Comment: @JohnColeman Indeed it is. I just wanted to explain it as simple and extended as possible as the OP said is new to Python.